# Strange behavior of unset in foreach by reference loop

Tags: php, foreach, reference

I know one should not modify physical structure of array while looping by reference, but I need explanation of what is going on in my code. Here we go:

```
$x= [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]];
foreach ($x as $i => &$upper) {
    print $i;
    foreach ($x as $j => &$lower) {

        if($i == 0 && $j == 2) {
            unset($x[2]);
        } else if($i == 1 && $j == 3) {
            unset($x[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is `01`. Surprising that outer loop iterates only twice, for indices `0` and `1`. I was expecting the output to be `014`.

I have read lots of blog posts and questions about hazards of using array references, but nothing that can explain this phenomenon. I am breaking my head over it for hours now.

## EDIT:

The code above is the minimal reproducible code. One explanation (but an *incorrect* one) that might seem to be the case is this:

*The outer loop goes through two iterations before the internal pointer is set to index `2`. But the loop does not find any element at index `2` and thus thinks no elements are left and quits.*

The problem with this theory is it doesn't quite explain this code:

```
$x= [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]];
foreach ($x as $i => &$upper) {
    print $i;
    foreach ($x as $j => &$lower) {

        if($i == 0 && $j == 2) {
            unset($x[2]);
            // No if else here
            unset($x[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

By the same token, the above code should also produce `01`, but its actual output is `014`, as expected. Even when two items in a series are removed, php knows that are still elements left to be iterated over. Could this possibly be a bug with php scripting engine?

Comment: What are you expecting then?

Comment: add some debug output. put a `var_dump($x)` into various parts of the code and you'll see exactly what's happening to the array.

Comment: @RahilWazir I am expecting `014`. @Marc B I have debugged it and observed all the variables, but can't figure it out. A lead here would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is you are unsetting the values during the foreach and causing php to break because the foreach is being modified during its loop.  I would rethink your logic and either make a copy of the array which you unset or try something different.

Comment: @chadpeppers where does it say the foreach breaks after modifying it?

Comment: @JuzerAli Put this `echo "(i$i-j$j-x".implode("",array_map(function($arr) {return $arr[0];},$x)) . ")";` just after `continue'` and look yourself. I get this: 0(i0-j1-x01234)(i0-j2-x01234)(i0-j3-x0134)(i0-j4-x0134)1(i1-j3-x0134)(i1-j4-x014)

Comment: @JuzerAli : see my answer for a guess on my side.

Comment: @nl-x please read the PHP manual Note:
When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call reset() before a foreach loop.
As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @nl-x see my *edit*. The case cannot be explained with any of the theories we have discussed so far.

Comment: Did you mean https://eval.in/private/2363b8dbc6c789 ?

Comment: @juzerali I agree with you. Strange

Comment: I made some fiddles: http://codepad.org/LdoLBzL1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple code to reproduce your issue:

```
$x = [0, 1, 2];
foreach ($x as $k => &$v) {
    print $k;
    if ($k == 0) {
        unset($x[1]);
    }
    end($x); // move IAP to end
    next($x); // move IAP past end (that's the same as foreach ($x as $y) {} would do)
}
```

If you foreach over an array, it's copied (= no problem when iterating, you'll iterate over the full original array).
But if you foreach by reference, the array is *not* copied (the reference needs to match the original array, so copying impossible).

Foreach internally always saves the position of the next element to iterate over.
But when the next position of an array is removed, foreach needs to go back to the array and check it's internal array pointer (IAP).

In this case the next position is destroyed *and* the IAP is past the end, it ends the loop.

That's what you're seeing here.

---

Also interesting: hhvm has a different behaviour to php here: http://3v4l.org/81rl8

---

Addendum: The infinite foreach loop:

```
$x = [0,1,2];
foreach ($x as $k => &$v) {
    print $k;
    if ($k == 1) {
        unset($x[2]);
    } else {
        $x[2] = 1;
    }
    reset($x);
}
```

If you understood my explanations above, guess why that loops indefinitely.

Comment: So you say foreach uses its own pointer and when that one fails it uses the array internal pointer. But then I agree that with OP's edit the '4' should not print as well, but it does...

Comment: @nl-x which one is your problem? where you remove 2 and 3 at $i == 0? well, there you don't remove the next entry to be iterated over, but only one later, so no problem. The important position is always only the next one, everything else is fetched anew from the (in this case not copied) array.

Comment: If I follow your logic, when I "Remove 2 and 3 at i0j2", the outer foreach should finish 0, go through 1 and run into a missing '2'. Then look at the internal array pointer and see it at the end of the array (where the previous loop (1) left it off)

Comment: @nl-x no. foreach stores 1 as next key. Prints 0. Stores 4 as next key. Prints 1. Stores 5 as next key. Prints 4. Sees end of array. Prints 5. Quit loop. It's just a problem when the stored key misses at the point where it wants to fetch the next value.

Comment: You say 5 , but you mean 2 ?

Comment: @nl-x no? Read again. Arrays have some order. It uses this order. All what happens is that it advances to the next array key before using the current key.

Comment: Ok, you mean, it starts, goes to 0, stores next entry 1, processes 0. Then it goes to the stored 1, now stores next entry 4 (because 2 and 3 were removed already at 0), processes 1. Then it goes to the stored 4, sees nothing else to store, processes 4. End.

Comment: And the one that breaks: it starts, goes to 0, stores 1, processes 0. Then it goes to the stored 1, stores next entry 2, processes 1. Then tries to go to the stored 2 but fails, as it was just now removed. As a backup it looks at the internal array pointer, and sees it at the end where the loop of 1 left it off, and stops.

Comment: @bwoebi You meant `foreach ($x as $y) {}` or `foreach ($x as &$y) {}`

Comment: @JuzerAli Doesn't make any difference.